# Spring Security JSP Login Page Problems

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm an absolute spring Amateur. So please help me. I want to protect my Site, redirect to a custom .jsp Login Page and after a successful Login the page should be "free".

With my actual Project, i became redirect to the Loginpage, which looks not like i want it to, but i cant log in.

My Code:

**AppConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "de.dashboard.spring.web" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("test").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .csrf();
  }
}
```

**Controller.Java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                          @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                          Model model) {

    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }

    //Only as test (doesn't work)
    model.addAttribute("error","Test");
    return "login";

  }
}
```

My login.jsp in under webapp/pages/login.jsp
**login.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
    .error {
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #a94442;
        background-color: #f2dede;
        border-color: #ebccd1;
    }

    .msg {
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #31708f;
        background-color: #d9edf7;
        border-color: #bce8f1;
    }

    #login-box {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

<h1></h1>

<div id="login-box">

<h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="error">${error}</div>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty msg}">
    <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
</c:if>

<form name='loginForm'
      action="<c:url value='/login' />" method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                                   value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}" />

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When the Login Page opened, it looks like:

[image: loginpage]

If i press on submit, the site refreshes. Please help :D

**EDIT**

jstl dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @Hema how do i do that? And i think the first line in the .jsp shouldn't be shown on the page, their is something wrong and i don't know what

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> replace this

Comment: @Hema don't i need it? Because i use he "c"?

Comment: Then y is tht tag being printed on ur UI..?

Comment: Just check if ur getting any errors..?

Comment: No, their are no errors :/ @Hema

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> the same tag am using in my project.which is working fine without any issue